# How to optimize conditional statements in my code

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array named `extraRank` which holds other users arrays named **userA**, **userB**, **userC** and **userD** whenever I push them into it:

```
// users arrays:
userA = ["Sara Ree",18, "Doctor", "441", "31"];
userB = ["Marry",18, "Nurse", "41", "1"];
userC = ["John Doe",18, "Woker", "21", "31"];
userD = ["Alex Morph",18, "Musisian", "81", "51"];

// users arrays may be pushed to this array  
let extraRank = [];
```

what I want is an efficient way to do this:

first, check which users arrays exist in `extraRank`.

then if for example, **userA** exist do this:

if `extraRank.indexOf(userA) == 0` then assign `userA_Index = 10;`

if `extraRank.indexOf(userA) == 1` then assign `userA_Index = 9;`

if `extraRank.indexOf(userA) == 2` then assign `userA_Index = 8;`

if `extraRank.indexOf(userA) == 3` then assign `userA_Index = 7;`

**I know one way is to this using if statements** for each user, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it...

Comment: Why are you using array for your users, and not objects ?

Comment: Because I'm going to pull them from the server and that way I just can send arrays from server to javascript (Correct me if it's not the best way)

Comment: Also, most efficient regarding what ? Code size, coding time, execution time ?

Comment: execution time...

Comment: how can u check array with array  in indexOf funciton ? will it work- for me it return -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the assignment is linear, as suggested by your example, you can do a simple subtraction:

```
userA_index = 10 - extraRank.indexOf(userA)
```

If it is more complex, you can create a map object that connects the index to the result, such as:

```
const mapIndexToOutput = {
  0: 10,
  1: 9,
  2: 8,
  3: 7,
  ...
}

userA_index = mapIndexToOutput[extraRank.indexOf(userA)]
```

Comment: Thank you that's it... I'm going to create a map object... plus 1+

Comment: what if the `indexOf` returns `-1`?

Comment: You add -1 to the map with the value you want to map with the items returning -1

Answer (score 1):

I don't totally understand your requierement, but would a simple substraction do the trick ?

```
userA_Index = 10 - extraRank.indexOf(userA)
```

But I'm not sure of what you want to achieve here.

**Edit:** You say that you want to optimize for execution time. This will be more efficient that a bunch of if. However, I don't think even 10 `if` statements are going to be noticeable.
How slow is your code now ? How many `user` do you have ?
You migth have other place to optimise first, but it is hard to say without a larger view of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... plus one